# Is it safe to move Craft Commerce Templates out of Plugin

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I installed Craft Commerce 2 and the templates are in vendor/craftcms/commerce/templates/shop. Is it safe to move these to my craft templates folder like this?

```
├── storage
...
│   └── runtime
├── templates
│   └── shop
├── vendor
```

Or are they where they are for a reason?

I don't really like the idea of drilling down into the vendor plugin directories to make changes, especially if they can be overwritten by composer during an update.

I don't want to introduce future problems.

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy them into your `templates` folder if you want to use them as a starting point.

I've added a mention of that into the installation docs here: https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/v2/installation.html#example-templates